# How to link data from a CSV table to a shapefile

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I've recently started using QGIS and have been doing alright at self teaching myself. I have read a few similar questions however I have not got this to work for myself.

I have a shapefile which maps a variety of areas, I am trying to link numerical data inputted from a CSV table. The table has unique identifiers which can be linked to the shapefile.

I've tried using the add vector join function to link the data however when applied I can not find the linked data anywhere in the fields section.

I want to show the data from the table on the shapefile to show a gradient difference however the column from the CSV file does not show up on the shapefile properties.

Also, when I leave the layer properties section after joining the table, when I go back inot the properties it is no longer there?

Not sure if there is something simple I've missed?

Comment: Please describe your process of joining more detailed.

Comment: Enter the properties section of the shape file - joins - add - select table as join layer - join and target fields are the identifiers from both files. I'm a bit lost at this point and have tried several options ranging from just clicking the cache join layer, also tried clicking the joined fields and selected the data I want to bring into the shape file. All of these have had the same result of not working

Comment: What is wrong with the tool `join attributes by field/value`?

Comment: When I press ok it shows that the join layer is applied in the 'join' section - I press 'apply' - The data is not shown in the 'fields' section - If I exit the layer properties and re-enter it the join no longer exists.

Comment: `join attributes by field/value` is a different tool. Please give it a try.

Comment: Unsure of where this is. However I have fixed the problem now. I have removed the csv data file and re-added it and now it works as intended. I think I either made a mistake in the process of adding the table file in or, I may have broken the file through the many different attempts playing around with it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The toolbox has a search-field, which you can use to browse for tools which might fit your purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be a bit more explicit about what you have tried.

Suggest the following;
- LAYER|ADD LAYER|ADD VECTOR LAYER - add the shapefile
- LAYER|ADD LAYER|ADD DELIMITED TEXT LAYER - NO GEOMETRY - hopefully follow the rest of that through

Now the above, need to have a common key. One column of each, need to have the same type of data, saying 1, 2, 3. Or Onion, Apple, Orange. The computer will match Apple:Apple 1:1 2:2. No more no less.

To tell it to do this, you right click on the Layer for the shapefile and goto the PROPERTIES dialog. This will contain an option to JOIN(S). In there, specific the target column for the key and it's matching column in the csv layer.

There is also another feature in project properties, call RELATIONS. I don't think it is relevant to your scenario.

Let us know how you go.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did follow that process initially however I must have made an error somewhere. I removed my table data file and re-added it following your process and it is working now. Thank you!

Comment: for future reference, the manual https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#joins-properties

Answer (score 1):

You can add data to your shape file in different ways.

One way that works for me is:

- Have the shape file (like boundaries of places etc)
- Open the csv file as text layer
- Join those two by the unique identifier they share (like an ID)
- Create a new field in the attribute table for a value you would like to join
- Fill that field with the existing data from the joined CSV file
- Save the shape file

You will find the "join" option in your layer properties (right click on that layer in the layer tree, select "properties").

I basically followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2KZqx1C0LU